# sqlalchemy constraint on a boolean column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint, check-constraints

I have a table with 3 columns A(, B, C) and have 2 constraints

1. A and B should be jointly unique which I have done by defining a unique  constraint.
2. For any given value in A, there can be only one True in C. (A, C=True) has to be unique. 
   I need help in defining the second constraint.

e.g Data set

### A      :         B              C

a1      :        b1      :       False

a1       :       b2     :        True

a1        :      b3       :      False

a2         :     b1      :       True

a2          :    b2      :       False

a2           :   b3   :          False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this can be expressed in a database-portable way without changing the schema. Partial index can do this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX One_C_Per_A_Idx ON Table(A) WHERE C;
```

But it is only available on PostgreSQL and SQL Server (and simulated with functional index on Oracle). With PostgreSQL back-end you can use `postgresql_where` keyword argument to `Index` (see [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/postgresql.html#partial-indexes)) to define partial index in SQLAlchemy.

A portable way is to split this into at least two tables, converting explicit boolean column into an implicit "present in the referencing table" expression. SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    a integer NOT NULL,
    b integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
);

CREATE TABLE flagged (
    a integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    b integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (a, b) REFERENCES my_table(a, b)
);
```

Query to get equivalent of the original table:

```
SELECT t.a, t.b, f.a IS NOT NULL AS c
FROM my_table t LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged f ON t.a = f.a AND t.b = f.b;
```

I'll omit SQLAlchemy model definitions for now, because I am not sure which solution suits your needs the best.